# How do I vectorise an accuracy metric computation?

Tags: python, performance, vectorization

I am writing my own accuracy function (num correct predictions / total predictions) for some given truth labels e.g. `[0, 1, 1, ...]` and probabilities e.g. `[[0.8, 0.2], [0.3, 0.7], [0.1, 0.9] ...]`. I don't want to use a library function such as sklearn's `accuracy_score()`.

I have created this version using a for loop:

```py
def compute_accuracy(truth_labels, probs):
    total = 0
    total_correct = 0
    for index, prob in enumerate(probs):
        predicted_label = 0 if prob[0] > 0.5 else 1
        if predicted_label == truth_labels[index]:
            total_correct += 1
        total += 1
    if total:
        return total_correct / total
    else:
        return -1
```

I now wish to make this more efficient by vectorising it. I'm aiming to check if the probabilities > 0.5 match the truth labels:

```py
import numpy as np

def compute_accuracy(truth_labels, probs):
    return ((np.array(probs[:][value_of_truth_labels_at_same_index]) > 0.5).astype(int) == np.array(truth_labels)).mean()
```

At this point I'm not sure how to pull out `value_of_truth_labels_at_same_index` without going back to for loops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
N = 10
X = np.random.randint(0,2,(N,))
p = np.random.random((N,2))
acc = np.mean(np.argmax(p, axis=1) == X)*100
print(f'Accuracy: {acc}%')
```

Comment: Thanks! For completeness: `return np.mean(np.argmax(probs, axis=1) == truth_labels)`